# hijacking home_url for root relative paths

Tags: urls, paths, home-url

I'd been having trouble with the full domain name being written into the path of links and assets. Basically localhost:XXXX works fine, until I try to reach my site from a Virtual Box install of XP or in my local network, where the domain changes to computername.local:XXXX

I managed to solve this problem with a tip from http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/06/relative-urls.html (code below)

The problem is that home_url which is referenced throughout my theme still returns the full domain, rather then just "/" as root. is there a way to filter home_url to do this? yes I could `define('WP_HOME',    '/' );` which will brute force the path, but causes other issues with feed readers and plugins - it also probably wont work with subdirectory installs.

thanks for your thoughts

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rw_relative_urls' );
    function rw_relative_urls() {
    // Don't do anything if:
    // - In feed
    // - In sitemap by WordPress SEO plugin
   if ( is_feed() || get_query_var( 'sitemap' ) )
     return;
    $filters = array(
    'post_link',
    'post_type_link',
    'page_link',
    'attachment_link',
    'get_shortlink',
    'post_type_archive_link',
    'get_pagenum_link',
    'get_comments_pagenum_link',
    'term_link',
    'search_link',
    'day_link',
    'month_link',
    'year_link',
     );
     foreach ( $filters as $filter )
{
    add_filter( $filter, 'wp_make_link_relative' );
}
    home_url($path = '', $scheme = null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in `wp-config.php` in a smarter way.  Like this:

```
<?php
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
// add the next line if you have a subdirectory install
define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME . '/path/to/wordpress');
```

This will solve your your issues with site URLs as they will be set dynamically on based on whatever the hostname is. This is the correct way to do this -- it's something I do on virtually ever WP install and it's even [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29).  Believe me, [you don't really want relative urls](http://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/).

Comment: What happens if the site is accessible by both HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: Look at how WP's [`is_ssl`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L3164) works, use a similar logic in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Thanks. What is the benefit of hard coding the protocol versus using a protocol relative URL?

Comment: `WP_HOME` is used other places than just in links to stylesheets and such -- namely permalinks. You can try it, it just might be a little weird.

Specifying a protocol relative WP content URL is usually okay, however.

Comment: Thanks @chrisguitarguy. After messing around with `define('WP_HOME', '/foo');` I realized that it breaks the TinyMCE editor, because the editor isn't smart enough to handle relative URLs to its javascript assets.

Comment: hi @chrisguitarguy please let me know if you know How do to the same in multisite?

Here is the sample of code in wp-config right now
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'abc.com' );
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/folder/');
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`home_url` calls `get_home_url` which has the filter `home_url`:

```
return apply_filters( 'home_url', $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id );
```

see [`/wp-includes/link-template.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1849)

Comment: Humm - I've done as much. Basically I revised get_home_url and put it in a functionality plugin, just to see.

Comment: I revised get_home_url and tried it in a functionality plugin, as wellas in the functions.php of child and parent. 

`function tr_get_home_url( $blog_id = null, $path = '', $scheme = null ) {
    $orig_scheme = $scheme;
        $scheme = 'http';
        $url = '/';
    if ( !empty( $path ) && is_string( $path ) && strpos( $path, '..' ) === false )
        $url .= '/';
    return apply_filters( 'home_url', $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id );
}`

With no effect––So I guess that this would mean that home_url is already being filtered elsewhere in the theme?

Comment: FYI this query is related to https://github.com/retlehs/roots/issues/490

Comment: @orionrush you're not filtering it correctly, you need to attach your filter function to `home_url` with [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter). The `apply_filter` code I gave above is where the filter is actually applied in source.